# Cache values between requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a (tableless) options model, which reads it's values from a yaml file. The yaml is part of the project, so if I keep my workflow, the options cannot change without redeploying and restarting the entire application. So it's not necessary to read and parse the file on every request. Because of this, I would like to cache the values between the requests.

So far, I've load the options into a class variable (`@@options`), but I'm not sure, if there is a better way.

(Do not say the session. These options aren't session variables, since they apply to all requests from all clients. Also I'm using the CookieStore)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Rails cache store](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html).

To write to the cache:

```
Rails.cache.write(key, value)
```

To read from the cache:

```
Rails.cache.read(key)
```

Comment: To complete the answer: Use `Rails.cache.write(key, value)` and `Rails.cache.read(key)`